# URL Scheme sometime launch App Store after application

Tags: ios, swift, url-scheme

I use in my app url scheme and I don't know why **sometime** when I click on URL (e.g.  https://api.domain.com/menu?id=7ee5232764-0a79-4afe) iOS opens my app (correct) and 1 second later opens App Store application (not correct). This is my openUrl's method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:] ) -> Bool {        
    let components = url.absoluteString.components(separatedBy: "/")
    if components.contains("menus") {
        let menuId = url.lastPathComponent
        let menu = Menu(id: menuId)
      SessionManager.shared.navigationManager.present(NavigationItem.menu(menu: menu).viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: have you added the breakpoints when ever your above function called when you click on url.

Comment: Is it just for me his posted URL actually opens a sexlink?

Comment: I don’t think it’s a good idea to click this xxx. com link.

Comment: I used "xxx" to replace original link. 

@MandeepSingh yes I used breakpoints and it enter correctly in the if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! Bug is on the web side where they have activated a JS timeout that they don't stop after app is opened.